# Android String format not working

Tags: java, android, string, format

I have a problem with `String.format` In android I want replace **{ 0 }** with my id.
My this code not working:

```
String str = "abc&id={0}";
String result = String.format(str, "myId");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you  should use replace method instead of format.

```
String str = "abc&id={0}";
str.replace("{0}","myId");
```

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 ways to do that and you are mixing them :)

1.String format:

```
String str = "abc&id=%s";//note the format string appender %s
String result = String.format(str, "myId");
```

or

2.Message Format:

```
String str = "abc&id={0}"; // note the index here, in this case 0
String result = MessageFormat.format(str, "myId");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your integer value as a seperate variable.

```
String str = "abc&id";
int myId = 001;
String result = str+myId;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
String result = String.format("abc&id=%s", "myId");
```

edit if you want more than one id,

```
String.format("abc&id=%s.id2=%s", "myId1", "myId2");
```

Comment: Thank you, but this not my expect.
ex: String str = "abc&id1={0},id2={1},..."

Comment: But you didn't state it in your quesiton, how can we know that?

Comment: String.format("abc&id=%s.id2=%s", "myId1", "myId2");

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're looking for is:

```
String str = "abc&id=%1$d";
String result = String.format(str, id);
```

`$d` because it's a decimal.

Other use case:

```
String.format("More %2$s for %1$s", "Steven", "coffee");
// ==> "More coffee for Steven"
```

which allows you to repeat an argument any number of times, at any position.